how to reference a data frame in local work library in r markdown
I can find a lot of documentation for Markdown online but I can't seem to find any answers regarding how to reference a dataframe in my Global Environment or in my local work folder.
All of the Markdown documentation seems to work fine when authors of documentation make examples based on mtcars or iris datasets or whatever is already in R memory. But if I do the same procedures referring my own dataframes, it doesn't work.
I read that it is because Markdown sets up a separate work environment but I can't find any descriptions of where it is or how to reference it.
For instance, if I have a dataframe "df" and I want to put a summary in my Markdown - how would I do that?

The most straightforward approach is to include the code that creates your dataframe directly in the R Markdown document. You can use echo = FALSE if you don't want this code to appear in the final document:
```{r, echo=FALSE} 
df <- read_csv("path/to/your/file.csv")
```

